# Add marker in Google Maps - Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

Please help me overcome this problem.
I have database that stores some points of Google Maps (lat, lng), and I want to display them in Google Maps.
Here's my controller

```
@location = SharedInfo.all
```

Here's the javascript in view

```
function DisplayTraficCir(loca) {
for (var location in loca){
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude)
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map
  });
}
// map.setCenter(location);
}
```

I called this function by:

```
DisplayTraficCir(<%@location%>);
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. Maybe it not execute code block inside "for" statement at all.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Maps API is not a Ruby API. It is a JavaScript API.

You say you are calling a JavaScript function like this:

```
DisplayTraficCir(<%@location%>);
```

But that is not true. That is your *Ruby* template code, not your JavaScript code.

You are trying to debug two problems at once. Instead, debug one problem at a time:

1. How to get the Maps API working with JavaScript, CSS, and HTML. Ruby, Rails, and your server code are not involved with this *at all*.
2. Once you have working JavaScript, CSS, and HTML code, how to generate that code from Rails.

In other words, to debug your JavaScript code, look at the *JavaScript* code, not the Ruby code that generates it.

You can debug JavaScript code using the developer tools in any browser. Chrome is particularly good. One easy thing to do is to insert this statement immediately before the function call in question:

```
debugger;
```

Then load your page with the Chrome developer tools open, and it will stop in the JavaScript debugger at that line. Then you can look at variables, look at the actual code the browser sees, trace through your code line by line, and all sorts of good things like that.

While doing this, forget *completely* about your Rails code. It isn't relevant at all at this point. The browser never sees that code, all it sees is the JavaScript *generated* by your Ruby code.

Separating this debugging task into two separate pieces like this will make it much easier to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Does it have someway pass the instance "@location" in function "DisplayTraficCir(...);", Michael Geary?

Comment: `@location` is Ruby code. It isn't JavaScript. Forget the Ruby code while you're debugging your JavaScript, and instead look at the actual JavaScript code that the browser sees. You won't find `@location` in the browser, or at least you shouldn't. The JavaScript code downloaded to the browser is the only thing that matters, not the Ruby code that generates it. You can use the developer tools in Chrome or other browsers to inspect this JavaScript code.